# ValueError: Expected object or value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to import a sample json file into pandas dataframe

I already tried [ValueError: Expected object or value when reading json as pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287011/valueerror-expected-object-or-value-when-reading-json-as-pandas-dataframe)

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bd3924a4e6a1> in <module>()
      1 # working with json
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 df = pd.read_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sample3.json", lines=True)
      4 df.head()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1117         if orient == "columns":
   1118             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1119                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1120             )
   1121         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

**1 Try :**

```
# working with json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sample3.json") 
#df = pd.read_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sample3.json", lines=True)  #also tried 
#df = pd.read_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sample3.json", lines=True, orient='records') # also tried 
#df = pd.read_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sample3.json", orient=str) # also tried 
df.head()
```

**Json File :**

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

Comment: `color` and `value` should be inside double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### That is not valid JSON.

JSON must have its objects' keys quoted with double quotes, like so:

```
{
    "color": "red",
    "value": "#f00"
}
```

Comment: Please convert this to a comment.

Comment: This is a valid answer to the question, it shouldn't be a comment. The hint for comments specifically say "avoid answering questions in comments".

Comment: @quamrana why would it be a comment?

Comment: As an answer it’s not very full.

Comment: it is exactly the answer to OP's question though is it not? (granted that @Kraigolas provided alot of extra content in his :) )

Comment: @quamrana [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266955/11659881) supports this answer.

Comment: While this answer certainly contains true statements, I’m not yet clear about what problem the OP actually has.

Comment: Ok, you’ve got an accepted answer. The OP has spoken.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually just a JSON problem. If I create your JSON file in my IDE, I immediately get formatting errors because the file is not properly encoded. It says:

```
property keys must be doublequoted
```

If I make the replacements

```
[
    {
        "color": "red",
        "value": "#f00"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "value": "#0f0"
    }
]
```

I can now use

```
df = pd.read_json("file.json") 
print(df)
```

to get

```
   color value
0    red  #f00
1  green  #0f0
```

Comment: you went above and beyond with this excellent answer :) imho