# How to Read Huge and Valid JSON File Line by Line in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've been trying to use this code to read a huge JSON file (It contains 80+ million records) line by line:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


lines = []

with open('file_path','r') as f:
    for line in f:
            lines.append(json.loads(line))      
            df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

But this gives an error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Then, I used replace function with below code,

```
import json
import pandas as pd


lines = []
jstr = ""


with open('filepath','r') as f:
    for line in f:
            jstr = f'{jstr}{line}'
            jstr = line.replace("'", '"')
            lines.append(json.loads(jstr))
            df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

But I can only read first six rows and then I got this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter
```

It is ensured that json is a valid format but I don't know what to do.

Would anyone help me how to handle this problem?

Comment: Is the a reason you're trying to read it in line-by-line as opposed to all at once?

Comment: Yes, when I tried to read it once it causes memory error. As I said, the file is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you searching this?

```
from pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data/simple.json')
```

Comment: It gives a MemoryError

Comment: I just find this:
`df = pd.read_json("test.json", orient="records", lines=True, chunksize=5)`
[source](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60268/load-large-jsons-file-into-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It works but when I try to convert it to dataframe, data = pd.DataFrame(df), it gives ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: @user13619579 could be this: Your JSON is malformed [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287011/valueerror-expected-object-or-value-when-reading-json-as-pandas-dataframe). You need to understand how the function [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) works to be able to use.

Comment: I tried everything but it doesn't work